# Split up date range into chunks to join back into one table KDB+/Q

Tags: time, kdb

I have a table that is being joined like so

```
result: select from table where date within (sd;ed)
```

where sd and ed span multiple months (like sd:2021.07.01 ed:2021.09.30). The table that I'm querying from has a break if you take more than a month, so to get the result I need, I have to do something like the following:

```
result: uj(uj(select from table where date within (2021.07.01;2021.07.30);select from table where date within (2021.08.01;2021.08.31));select from table where date within (2021.09.01;2021.09.30))
```

How can I make this dynamic for any sd and ed? That is, how can I break up time range into first days of months, last days of months, and join them all into one table cleanly? My initial idea was to divide the days in the range x amount of time, to be input by a user, then add the number of days that results to the sd to get frames, but that got messy.

Comment: Another idea I just had was to take the month of sd and ed, make a list of the months in between, then change the query to "where date.month=x". The problem with this is sd might not be the start of a month, and ed might not be the end of a month. Like this could be sd:2021.07.14 instead of 2021.07.01

Comment: ```select from table where date within (2021.08.01;2021.07.31)``` This doesn't look right to me, should these dates be flipped?

Comment: If you are seeing issues when selecting in a range of dates (errors etc.) then that likely points to your underlying database containing errors and inconsistencies between partitions. This a fairly common issue to run into and solutions exist. https://kx.com/blog/kdb-q-insights-database-maintenance-with-q/ see here for one example.  In general using the workaround you mentioned may help now but for a long term solution you should correct the underlying data if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should chunk it for you:

```
raze{select from t where date within x}each(first;last)@\:/:d group"m"$d:sd+til 1+ed-sd
```

Do *not* use `where date.month=x` as you had suggested - at least not for historical queries

Answer (score 2):

One option for converting your start and end dates into an iterable list of dates might be:

```
f:{0N 2#(x,raze -1 0+/:`date$mx+1+til(`month$y)-mx:`month$x),y}
```

Where x is start date and y is end date.

```
f[2021.07.14;2022.02.09]
2021.07.14 2021.07.31
2021.08.01 2021.08.31
2021.09.01 2021.09.30
2021.10.01 2021.10.31
2021.11.01 2021.11.30
2021.12.01 2021.12.31
2022.01.01 2022.01.31
2022.02.01 2022.02.09
```

Then you could run:

```
{select from t where date within x} each f[sd;ed]
```

And join the results using `raze` or `(uj/)`